# Obtaining Multiple Textbox ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, focus, placeholder

I have this code here in ASP.NET format

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BuildingNameTextBox" runat='server' placeholder="Building Name" Text='<%# Bind("BuildingName") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Example: 8th Floor, Sun Life Centre, 5th Avenue corner Rizal Drive, Fort Bonifacio Taguig City" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" placeholder="Use the autocomplete." runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="RegionTextBox" placeholder="Use the autocomplete." runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>' class="subMarkets"/>
```

and this code in javascript

```
$("#BuildingNameTextBox").data("holder", $("#BuildingNameTextBox").attr("placeholder"));
            $("input").focusin(function () {
                $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
            });
            $("input").focusout(function () {
                $(this).attr("placeholder", $(this).data("holder"));
            });
```

The function of the javascript is to remove the placeholder when the textbox is in focus and restore the text of the appropriate textbox when not in focus
I can't seem to find a way to restore the appropriate text for the succeeding text boxes.

E.g. when I select the Building textbox, the next placeholder of the textbox will be replaced by the placeholder of the BuildingTextBox (Building).

I need to find a way to make the placeholder restore to the appropriate textbox. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a method that is called on the document ready that populates all of them, instead of just #buildingnametextbox:

```
$("input").each(function () {
    $(this).data("holder", $(this).attr("placeholder"));
});
```

OR

In your markup, add the data value:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="BuildingNameTextBox" runat='server' data-holder="Building Name" placeholder="Building Name" Text='<%# Bind("BuildingName") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server" data-holder="Example: 8th Floor, Sun Life Centre, 5th Avenue corner Rizal Drive, Fort Bonifacio Taguig City" placeholder="Example: 8th Floor, Sun Life Centre, 5th Avenue corner Rizal Drive, Fort Bonifacio Taguig City" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" data-holder="Use the autocomplete." placeholder="Use the autocomplete." runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' />
<asp:TextBox ID="RegionTextBox" data-holder="Use the autocomplete." placeholder="Use the autocomplete." runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Region") %>' class="subMarkets"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The placeholder will be removed as soon as the input is on focus, and if you enter any text, it won't show the placeholder anymore!

So, even if you change the placeholder value every time the "#buildingnametextbox" loses focus, it'll be useless, because you wouldn't use this. And let's assume that if user leave the field empty... This would empty the placeholder too, and i don't think you'd want this to happen :)